# How to add a scroll bar to my div without it blowing up my web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a real simple page that has a header, footer, body, and left and right nav's. 
All of them together make a nice rectangular page thats 100% of the width. 
All made using div's in a css sheet. 
I have 20 image thumbnails in the body and when the page is resized they push my footer out of place. 
To fix this i would like to add a scrollbar to the body div. 
I have already done this with overflow-y: auto;
However,
Adding the scrollbar seems to add some space to the right side of the body, forcing it to be placed underneath the left and right nav's blowing everything up. Please Help.

```
#headerElement {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
border: 2px solid #000000;
background-color: #F8AA3C;
}
#bodyElement {
    margin-left: 10%;
width:  80%; 
color:  blue;
height: 400px;
background-color:  #F8883C; 
border: 2px dashed #F8AA3C;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#leftNavigationElement {
float: left;
width: 10%; 
height: 400px;
border: 2px dashed #FF0000;
background-color: #8F883C;
}
#rightNavigationElement { 
float: right;
width: 10%; 
height: 400px;
border: 2px dashed #0000FF;
background-color: #F888FC;
}
#footerElement {
clear: both;
border: 2px dashed #00FFFF;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you can shoe us and HTML so we can try figure it out

Comment: could you show html too?

Answer (score 2):

Because the scroll bar is not inside the width of the div but still takes up space, you need to give it some space or negative margins. I would guess a width of 18 pixels for IE, and since you cannot set that in IE, that will have to be your default. [image: =(]

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 18px; margin-right:-18px; }
::-moz-scrollbar { width: 18px; margin-right:-18px;}
::-o-scrollbar { width: 18px; margin-right:-18px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either restructure the page so it flows better or force the scrollbar with {overflow-y: scroll} and adjust widths accordingly so the layout doesn't break.